# Can I use findByIdAndUpdate to increment the value of one object in an array (mongoose)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My schema for Events contains an array of objects named tickets:

```
tickets: [{
    ticketTypeID: Number,
    numberOfTickets: Number,
    }]
```

I want to use `Event.findByIdAndUpdate` to increment `numberOfTickets` in just one object in the array.

I want to do this in one call to the db.

This can be done in mongodb using the positional $ operator. Similar queries from a few years back say this can't be done on mongoose.

Has there been any update to enable this on mongoose and if so, how do I code for it?

Comment: Can you show the document you want to modify and why the way you're trying to use the positional operator?

Comment: You could probably use arrayFilters to select the element you want